# Tag synonym-request: [facebook-javascript-sdk] <- [facebook-jssdk]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

These tags both refer to the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

[facebook-javascript-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk) has 800
[facebook-jssdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-jssdk) has 84 and no tag info

Instead of bumping up these questions with tag edits, could [facebook-javascript-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk) be made the master?

Comment: +1. If I could suggest/vote this synonym, I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags have been merged and synonymized.

> ## Merge Results
>
> updating post history, 184 rows affected
> updating posts, 164 rows affected
> updating PostTags associations, 144 rows affected
> removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
> updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
> **tag remapping of [facebook-javascript-sdk] and [facebook-jssdk] complete!**
> remapping 0 synonyms
> 8 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
> **Tag Synonym facebook-jssdk -> facebook-javascript-sdk was approved!**
> Broadcasting tag-engine reload

Answer (score 0):

I have just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258590/why-does-the-facebook-javascript-sdk-request-all-these-files) about the Facebook JavaScript SDK and was about to propose this change myself when I noticed your question. However, I also noticed that the [facebook-jssdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-jssdk) tag now does have a tag wiki excerpt, which is identical to that of [facebook-javascript-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk).

I think this is just going to lead to further confusion when tagging a question - I chose the "facebook-javascript-sdk" tag purely because it has more questions (1027). "facebook-jssdk" has 147.

I do not have the required upvotes in those tags to propse the synonym, so hopefully someone else can get this done.